# Relation between MSE and variance of data

Tags: variance, mse

I am having a hard time understanding how to compare results of MSE and variance of data to eachother. I understand that MSE is used to calculate how far off data points are from a prediction, say you made linear regression, and that the variance tells us how far apart the data points are. Are these comparable? And if so, in what what?
If we take an example, where we have to do linear regression, and we get the variance of the data to be around 3-400, but the MSE is much higher like 50.000. How could we compare these two values? Is it a good fit if these two are approximately equal? Or is it a good fit even if the MSE is so much higher than the variance?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/590199/247274) discussion on the statistics Stack. // Feel free to write @Dave if you want to ask why I find that to be such a related discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You really cannot directly compare the variance in data to the variance in errors within say a linear regression.

Looking at a simple regression and making the assumption that you have built a proper model with no pattern in the residuals:

The variance in the predictor variable is a factor of the nature of that variable itself.

So long as the variance is not due to some kind of anomaly in the system (poor measurement accuracy or something) then that is simply the accepted and natural range of values the predictor could take.

The variance in the MSE (mean squared error) is residual error, which is defined as UNEXPLAINED variance. This means that it is the amount of change in Y not explained by X.

Because this is a subset of the variance of Y, and particularly referring to variance in Y not related to X, then there is no way to align the variance in your predictors to the variance unexplained by that predictor in your outcome variable.